# Finding similar strings with restricted alpha characters using Python

Tags: python, similarity, levenshtein-distance, difflib

I want to group similar strings, however, I would prefer to be smart to catch whether conventions like '/' or '-' are diverged instead of letter differences.

Given following input:

```
moose
mouse
mo/os/e
m.ouse

alpha = ['/','.']
```

I want to group strings with respect to restricted set of letters, where output should be:

```
moose
mo/os/e

mouse
m.ouse
```

I'm aware I can get similar strings using [difflib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/difflib.html) but it doesn't provide option for limiting the alphabet. Is there another way of doing this? Thank you.

**Update:**

Instead of restricted letters, alphas are simpler to implement by just checking for occurrences. Therefore, I've changed the title.

Comment: Have you considered casefolding and stripping away anything that's not within `a-z`?

Comment: Can you add some other examples? Can `/` appear anywhere in the word, e.g., `/moose` or `moose/`? Can the restricted symbols appear more than once? Can they co-occur?

Comment: Yes, anywhere and they can occur more than once. I will improve the example shortly. @inspectorG4dget stripping away special chars, grouping them with exact match (maybe allowing space) may help. Thinking about it.

Comment: How about making a defaultdict(list) where keys are filtered words and values are lists of words?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I think your solution is simple and makes sense with exact matching. Levenshtein may not be needed at all in that case. @.hello_world, you are thinking about a similar solution as I understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
from collections import defaultdict

container = defaultdict(list)
for word in words:
    container[''.join(item for item in word if item not in alpha)].append(word)
```

Comment: Nice one, it works! I will wait a bit to see a if more of a non-exact solution comes along. Thank you.

Comment: Looks like there is no other way around as example I provided even ignores  a single letter difference, so this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea that takes a few (easy) steps:

```
import re
example_strings = ['m/oose', 'moose', 'mouse', 'm.ouse', 'ca...t', 'ca..//t', 'cat']
```

## 1. Index all of your strings so you can refer back to them by index later:

```
indexed_strings = list(enumerate(example_strings))
```

## 2. Store all strings with restricted characters in a dictionary using index as the key, string as the value. Then remove the restricted chars temporarily for sorting:

```
# regex to match restricted alphabet
restricted = re.compile('[/\.]')
# dictionary to store strings with restricted char
restricted_dict = {}
for (idx, string) in indexed_strings:
    if restricted.search(string):
        # storing the string with a restricted char by its index
        restricted_dict[idx] = string
        # stripping the restricted char temporarily and returning to the list
        indexed_strings[idx] = (idx, restricted.sub('', string))
```

## 3. Sort the cleaned list of strings by string values, then iterate over the strings once more and replace the stripped strings with their original values:

```
indexed_strings.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
# make a new list for the final set of strings
final_strings = []
for (idx, string) in indexed_strings:
    if idx in restricted_dict:
        final_strings.append(restricted_dict[idx])
    else:
        final_strings.append(string)
```

Result: `['ca...t', 'ca..//t', 'cat', 'm/oose', 'moose', 'mouse', 'm.ouse']`

Comment: It's interesting, but the complexity with an extra dict is totally unneeded. You use `sort` with a `key`. Why not use it with `lambda string: restricted.sub('', string)` directly?

Comment: @EricDuminil I agree and more generally I concede that the accepted answer is much more elegant and accomplishes everything the OP wants in a single pass :-)

Comment: I'm not sure the accepted answer is a single pass : it needs to iterate over every `alpha` char for every `item` in `words`. For your solution, I was just saying that `1` and `2` are unneeded.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to group words, you should probably use [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

You just need to define a function which deletes `alpha` chars (e.g. with [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate)), and you can apply [`sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) and [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to your data:

```
from itertools import groupby

words = ['moose', 'mouse', 'mo/os/e', 'm.ouse']
alpha = ['/','.']

alpha_table = str.maketrans('', '', ''.join(alpha))

def remove_alphas(word):
    return word.lower().translate(alpha_table)

words.sort(key=remove_alphas)
print(words)
# ['moose', 'mo/os/e', 'mouse', 'm.ouse'] # <- Words are sorted correctly.

for common_word, same_words in groupby(words, remove_alphas):
    print(common_word)
    print(list(same_words))
# moose
# ['moose', 'mo/os/e']
# mouse
# ['mouse', 'm.ouse']
```